# How to rename a specific word in a file name using python

Tags: python-2.7

This is my example code to rename the file name.

```
import os
import csv
import glob

file_pattrn = '*.*'
file_names = {}

with open('new.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
       file_names[row[0]] = row[1]

for file in glob.glob(file_pattrn):
    path, filename = os.path.split(file)
    filename_noext, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
    new_filename = file_names.get(filename_noext, filename_noext)
    os.rename(os.path.join(path, filename),
              os.path.join(path, '{}{}'.format(new_filename, ext)))
```

But this rename a whole file name.I want to rename a specific word in a file name with new name.
For example i have a file names as below.

1.AAAA_NI_MU.wav

2.AAAB_GH_TY.wav

3.BBBB_PO_WG.wav  like this .Here i need to rename First four characters to new name.
For new names i have kept a csv file as below.
[image: Example csv file]

Can you please guide me for this

Comment: Do you know how select characters (and character ranges) in a string?

Comment: I dnt know how to dot his

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code example, at line:

`new_filename = file_names.get(filename_noext, filename_noext)`

1. First solution is to replace it by:

   ```
   new_filename = filename_noext
   for key in file_names.keys():
     new_filename = new_filename.replace(key, file_names[key])
   ```

it actually solves you task by [replacing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) substrings in filename.

2. Other way:

   ```
   new_filename = "_".join([file_names.get(k, k) for k in filename_noext.split('_')])
   ```

This actually replaces only substrings separated by specific pattern ('_', in your case).

Answer (score 1):

I all you files have the pattern `xxxx_rest_of_the_file_name` and you want to replace the `xxxx` part, this could work:

```
for file in glob.glob(file_pattrn):
    path, filename = os.path.split(file)
    start, rest = file_name.split('_', 1)
    new_filename = '_'.join([file_names.get(start, start), rest])
    os.rename(os.path.join(path, filename),
              os.path.join(path, new_filename))
```

**EDIT**

Version that does not change names without an underscore.

```
for file_name in files:
    parts = file_name.split('_', 1)
    if len(parts) == 1:
        continue
    start, rest = parts
    new_filename = '_'.join([file_names.get(start, start), rest])
    print(new_filename)
```

Comment: I faced this error "    start, rest = filename.split('_', 1)
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack"

Comment: In this case your original does not contain an underscore. Added a version that accounts for this.